# XCode 6 Beta Clicking on png doesn't show image

Tags: xcode6

I created a new project via the Cocos2D iOS template and then copied some existing source files into the project.

If I open this project in XCode 5.1.1 I can view png images when I click on them in the source browser.  However in XCode Beta 6 I can only view a png image if it doesn't have a png extension.

Anyone have this issue or know how to get around it in XCode Beta 6?

Comment: Are you using the latest Beta? I just checked and was unable to replicate this problem. It could also (maybe) be that the image(s) in question are not actually PNG-encoded and were renamed with the wrong file extension.

Comment: @ReidBelton Upgrading to XCode 6 Beta 7 fixed it.  I didn't realize I had to manually update it.

Comment: Good! Yes, with beta versions of Xcode, you have to check the dev portal and download it yourself, it's not a normal update...reason being, people usually want to also have the release version installed simultaneously, and possibly multiple beta versions as well.